# how to extract a substring in R when it is in a variable of a dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, substring

I have one *Variable* (character type) of my *DataFrame* that can have strings such as:

```
"CORRECT_STRING 1 abcd"
"field"
"part"
"CORRECT_STRING 100 xvfgfjskk"
"behind"
"CORRECT_STRING 4 afdgdg"
"CORRECT_STRING 9 ahj"
"CORRECT_STRING 12 gsgkkd"
"extract"
"CORRECT_STRING 108 hfjfj"
"CORRECT_STRING 21 y"
```

I would like to create a subset of my *DataFrame* with only those rows in which *Variable* is equal to "CORRECT_STRING" regardless of what follows.

I have tried this:

```
library(gsubfn)
DataFrame <- DataFrame[(DataFrame$Variable == (strapplyc(DataFrame$Variable, "(.*)CORRECT_STRING", simplify = TRUE))),]
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone please let me know what I am missing? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `grepl`for this. If df is your dataframe and var the column n which you have the text shown in your example, this should work:

```
df[grepl("CORRECT_STRING",df$var),]
```

Comment: Great solution - easy and flexible. Thank you!